# Can we rely on Hyperledger Composer ACL for privacy?

Tags: acl, hyperledger-fabric, privacy, hyperledger-composer

Composer provides some pretty good ACL features, with enough granularity to prevent unauthorized access based on complex business logic.

I understand that using composer's APIs, an unauthorized user will not be able to read data.

However, what if the user uses Fabric's APIs? How does composer implement their ACL at the Fabric level? Is a business network sharing a single channel? In which case, does it mean that any participant/node can look at the block manually and see private data?

So my question is, can we rely on Composer and assume that if we correctly wrote our ACL file then the data is secured?

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what you mean when you say fabric api's ?

Comment: Well, I’m not familiar with Fabric’s API but I’m asking about *any* API that may compromise go around composer’s ACL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put it this way, the Composer ACLs are as secure as if you had written Fabric chaincode in Go and had included explicit conditional checks on what data a given transaction can access or update.

The data *is* stored unencrypted on the blockchain, and it *is* stored in world-state (in CouchDB for example). So if someone has local access to the files on disk, or the CouchDB database for world-state, they can circumvent the ACL rules. This is *not* specific to Composer however, and would apply equally to Fabric chaincode written in Go.

Comment: So my point is, assuming that participants will also own nodes in the network, there is no way to prevent them from unauthorized reads? Whether pure Fabric or with Composer?

Comment: Fabric (and Composer) supports the notion of channels to control how data is distributed across the peers. E.g. you can have a channel 1 between peers A and B, and a channel 2 between peers A and C. These essentially act as discrete ledgers. If the data is distributed everywhere, then all parties have the bytes (you are distributing the data you want to share). You could encrypt the bytes, but then you need to ensure that the right parties have the right private keys to decrypt the data. AFAIK Fabric does not help with this issue yet, so you'll have to deal with that out of band.

Comment: @DanSelman If we are using multiple channels for data privacy,  how can we leverage Hyperledger Composer? As the composer still supports only a single channel in the connection profile? Alternatively, if we protect this CouchDB instance with username/password, will it be a minor solution to this?