# Channels in Hyperlerdger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I could not find any mention of channels in the composer documentation.

How does Composer interact with multiple channels?

Does it only support One Business Network == One Channel ?
Meaning, if I want to have *some* transactions private between 2 parties, I need to create a separate business network from scratch? They won't share anything in the business models?

I am asking as a follow-up to [Can we rely on Hyperledger Composer ACL for privacy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47457566/25645)

Answer (score 0):

A Business Network is deployed to a channel.

By default Composer uses a Channel named "composerchannel" but can be easily configured to use a different channel.

The channel Composer uses is defined in the Business Network Card.  The channel being used can be seen using the command `composer card list --name <cardname>`

Using multiple channels would require multiple Business Network Cards.

Answer (score 0):

In the  version of composer>0.16 just open the network card that is deployed on your business network and in it there is a file connection.json where all relevant details are given there you can find channel name